# Get Top 20 IPs from access.log - sort by IP - add User Agent

Tags: linux, awk

With this command it is possible to get the top 20 Ips from apache access.log

```
cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```

I know, that User Agent could be displayed by:

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}'
```

or

```
cut -d\" -f 6
```

but how to combine this together?

I want a **sort by IP** and append the user agent behind the IP.

example:

```
544.45.234.5  Mozilla/5.0   (compatible;    bingbot/2.0;    +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `sed`.

```
cat access_log | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]\.]*\).*"\(.*\)"$/\1 \2/' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```

You are losing information with `awk '{print $1}'`, so you cannot get the user-agent later.

Comment: Thank you for getting into. When I use your command, The output is only 1 number.

Comment: I used the log format from https://kb.webtrends.com/articles/Information/Sample-Log-File-Apache-Extended-Log-File-Format and it works fine. Can you post a line from your log? The regex will need to be changed if your log format is different.

Comment: yes, sure:

913.211.12.323 - - [24/Mar/2017:06:06:34 +0100] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200                                                                               3619 "http://www.example.com/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Wi                                                                              ndows NT 6.1; 125LA; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21                                                                              022)"

Comment: `$ cat access_log | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]\.]*\).*"\(.*\)"$/\1 \2/' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20` gives me `1 913.211.12.323 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Wi ndows NT 6.1; 125LA; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21 022)` where 1 is the count of items. I am using GNU sed 4.2.2

Comment: If you don't want the count change `uniq -c` to just `uniq`

Comment: Thanks again. Ok, your code is working half. Your code make the sort with IP AND User Agent. What I need is that sort and group by comes only from the IP and the user agent is append. The row should be exaclty like this but with user agents: 

cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20

Is it possible to change your code in that way, sort only and group only by IP?

Comment: because If one IP has a differnt user agent all the time its not showing as a heavy IP. Thats the reason why I need the group by IP and sort by IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138964/discussion-between-gargsms-and-labu77).

Comment: It's a shame the chat link in the previous comment is 404ing